# unity create dll with editor x64

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, system.reflection

I need to create a dll using the editor 64bits to reuse in unity 64 bits environment...

to do this I've added this option:

```
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.CompilerOptions = "/platform:x64";
```

but i receive this error:

```
(0,0) : error CS8088: Your .NET Runtime does not support `PE32Plus'. Please use the latest Mono runtime instead.
```

and If I create a dll 32 bits, when I load with

```
assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(mydll.bytes);
```

it gives me the badimageformat...

where I can definetively resolve this issue?

Comment: Unity is designed to be cross platform, why would you do so?

Comment: @David 'cause I need to pack the scripts into an assetpackage and reuse into another project that loads the package... all the ways I try ends in front of a wall... :(